# Linux group permissions confusion

Tags: linux, apache, netbeans, user-permissions

I'm trying to set up a local only site on apache2 on my VM. I've not had problems doing this before but today I managed to get my self tangled in knots of confusion trying to work out what I'd missed and am still unable to work out the answer.

My `/var/www` folder looks like this:

```
acaeris@Jinx /var/www $ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May  3 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root     root     4096 May 28  2015 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 May 28  2015 html
```

`acaeris` is a member of the `www-data` group and Netbeans is running under `acaeris`:

```
acaeris@Jinx /var/www $ grep -i --color 'www-data' /etc/group
www-data:x:33:acaeris

acaeris@Jinx /var/www $ ps aux | grep 'netbeans'
acaeris   9235  0.0  0.1  12776  2756 ?        S    10:12   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/nbexec --userdir /home/acaeris/.netbeans/8.2 --cachedir /home/acaeris/.cache/netbeans/8.2 --jdkhome /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/bin/jre --branding nb --clusters /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/nb:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/ergonomics:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/ide:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/extide:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/java:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/apisupport:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/webcommon:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/websvccommon:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/enterprise:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/mobility:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/profiler:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/python:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/php:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/identity:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/harness:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/cnd:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/cndext:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/dlight:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/groovy:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/extra:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/javacard:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/javafx: -J-Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade -J-Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense -J-Xmx400m -J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
acaeris   9485  8.1 31.8 2762964 651800 ?      Sl   10:12   1:40 /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/bin/jre/bin/java -Djdk.home=/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/bin/jre -classpath /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/boot.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ja.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_pt_BR.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ru.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=/home/acaeris/.netbeans -Dnetbeans.running.environment=gnome -Dnetbeans.dirs=/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/nb:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/ergonomics:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/ide:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/extide:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/java:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/apisupport:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/webcommon:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/websvccommon:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/enterprise:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/mobility:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/profiler:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/python:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/php:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/identity:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/harness:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/cnd:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/cndext:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/dlight:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/groovy:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/extra:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/javacard:/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/javafx: -Dnetbeans.home=/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/platform -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade -Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense -Xmx400m -client -Xss2m -Xms32m -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -DaddExports:java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/acaeris/.netbeans/8.2/var/log/heapdump.hprof -splash:/home/acaeris/.cache/netbeans/8.2/splash.png org.netbeans.Main --cachedir /home/acaeris/.cache/netbeans/8.2 --userdir /home/acaeris/.netbeans/8.2 --branding nb
acaeris   9635  0.2  7.4 1031136 151764 ?      Sl   10:13   0:02 nodejs --harmony /home/acaeris/.netbeans/8.2/nbts-services.js
acaeris  10026  0.0  0.0  14224   940 pts/0    S+   10:33   0:00 grep --color=auto netbeans
```

Yet for some reason Netbeans is unable to create a folder in `/var/www` and neither can I in console without using sudo. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I forgot the vital step of restarting. Although I had joined the group, I wasn't currently logged in, in the group.